# Double parentheses to increment a variable in bash

Tags: bash, increment

Suppose I increment a variable in bash. For instance,

```
> i=0; for f in `ls *.JPG`; do echo $f $i; ((i++)); done
a0.jpg 0
a1.jpg 1
...
```

Now I wonder *why* I need those double parentheses to increment `i`.

Comment: You should also wonder why your method fails when you have filenames containing spaces, and how to remedy this. **Never parse the output of `ls`**. Go and see the guy who showed you `for f in \`ls *.JPG\`; do ...` and be mad at him.

Comment: I'd be pretty pissed if my shell incremented `clang` each time I typed `clang++ foo.cpp`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks. What would you recommend instead of `for f in \`ls *.JPG\``?

Comment: @Michael `for f in *.JPG; do ...` and please worship me forever for showing you good practices `:)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The double parentheses construct](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html) is a shell feature to support arithmetic operations. 
The same construct can also be used for [Loops](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html#FORLOOPC) and special [numerical constants](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/numerical-constants.html#NUMBERS).

Also, copied from the first link :

```
# -----------------
# Easter Egg alert!
# -----------------
#  Chet Ramey seems to have snuck a bunch of undocumented C-style
#+ constructs into Bash (actually adapted from ksh, pretty much).
#  In the Bash docs, Ramey calls (( ... )) shell arithmetic,
#+ but it goes far beyond that.
#  Sorry, Chet, the secret is out.
```

Answer (score 4):

`i++` is a perfectly valid file name, and if I have access to your system, I can make that into a command that does something you don't want.

Try creating a file, `/bin/i++` with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Gotcha'
```

and then `chmod +x /bin/i++`

Comment: In case you think this is theoretical, `g++` was (still is?) the GNU C++ compiler.

Comment: Incidentally, `((i++))` is also a perfectly valid filename, and in this regard, I don't really find your answer so much relevant.

Comment: An interesting and perfectly valid point, but not really an answer.

Comment: The point being, `i++` is only interpreted as a parameter expression inside `(( ... ))`. Otherwise, it's just a string which, on its own, will be interpreted as a command name.

Comment: As to the reason parens are magic and need to be escaped, but `+` isn't, this is probably a side effect of _bash_ trying to be backwards-compatible with its predecessor, _sh_, but I haven't found any good reference supporting that claim.